# Реализация докачивания файла HttpClient

Tags: c#

Разрабатываю приложение, которое должно скачать файл с web адреса на компьютер и дальше его обработать.
Задачу вроде реализовал, все работает и тут ко мне обратился клиент и говорит:

> У меня интернет медленный и имеет частые обрывы соединения, не можешь дать прямую ссылку, а то программа качает файл по новой.

И вот собственно я пытаюсь исправить эту проблему, а точнее надо сделать следующие 2 вещи:

1. Возобновление загрузки файла, после обрыва соединения. - Частично решил при помощи буфера, кратковременные обрывы вроде как говорят гасит.
2. Докачать уже имеющийся "Огрызок", который остался после предыдущего процесса неудачного скачивания.

Сейчас процесс скачивания файла выглядит примерно так:

```
private async Task ProcessContentStream(long? totalDownloadSize, Stream contentStream)
{
    var totalBytesRead = 0L;
    var readCount = 0L;
    var buffer = new byte[4096];
    var isMoreToRead = true;

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_destinationFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 4096, true))
    {
        do
        {
            var bytesRead = await contentStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                isMoreToRead = false;
                TriggerProgressChanged(totalDownloadSize, totalBytesRead);
                continue;
            }

            await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            readCount += 1;

            if (readCount % 100 == 0)
                TriggerProgressChanged(totalDownloadSize, totalBytesRead);
        }
        while (isMoreToRead);
    }
}
```

То есть мы с сервера берем кусок (буфер) и записываем его в `FileStream` до тех пор, пока сервер не отдаст нам весь файл.

Я пробовал:

- При запуске сдвигать позицию `Stream`'ов до `fileStream.Length` (текущего размера файла), но `HttpClient` отдает обычный `Stream`, который имеет `CanSeek = false`, то есть я не могу с сервера начать получать данные с определенной точки, только с самого начала.
- Я пробовал пропускать запись в файл (`await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);`) до тех пор, пока кол-во полученных с сервера данных не будет равно текущему размеру файла, то есть делаю нечто такое (набросок):

  ```
  if (totalBytesRead >= fileStream.Length)
      await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
  ```

  Но по ощущениям, из за `await contentStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);` я данные все равно качаю с сервера, но только не записываю, а в результате получаю битый файл, который имеет разрыв ровно в том месте, где остановилась загрузка. Тут скорей всего происходит подобное из за того, что буфер был не до конца записан при закрытие приложения и при повторной загрузке мне надо файл начать записывать на 1 "буфер" раньше, но как это сделать так и не понял.

Короче, я в тупике и без понятия как докачать уже существующий файл на диске, посла обрыва/закрытия приложения. Было бы супер, если бы вы научили меня брать с сервера байты с определенной позиции, не затрагивая начало (`Seek` в `Stream`), тогда можно наверно после разрыва запросить эти байты и продолжить закачку, или есть другие варианты?

Comment: _я не могу с сервера начать получать данные с определенной точки_ - но ты можешь указать в запросе с какого байта надо качать. Не совсем понятно, сервер тоже твой?

Comment: @Grundy Там есть файл с "зеркалами", из которого берется адрес. Мой сервер не всегда доступен может быть и на этот случай файлы размещены в облаках (которые имеют ограничения). В основном да, файл качается с моего IIS сервера по прямой ссылке. Хм, а как в запросе указать с какого места брать данные? Для своих тестов я использовал файлы [от сюда](http://www.ovh.net/files/) и проверял их потом по Md5.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, заголовок [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/Range) ? Разве нет? Только придется запоминать место разрыва, куда нибудь, например в кеш.

Comment: @ヒミコ Спасибо, попробую этот вариант, не знал.

Comment: Только не забудьте сначала сделать head запрос, прежде чем запрашивать контент. Сервер может отклонять или не поддерживать такие запросы.

Comment: Кстати, в дополнение к выше сказанному, можно файл разбить на куски и качать в несколько потоков, как делали качалки в старые добрые времена. Создать карту скачанных отрезков. А еще, быть может, в NuGet есть готовая либа, в которой уже всё это уже реализовано, стоит проверить.

Comment: @aepot Да вот не могу найти готовое решение, с радостью использовал бы. Все найденные мной библиотеки не имеют таких возможностей, только паузу (что реализовать довольно просто).

Comment: По буферу, его размер у вас 4096. Берете размер недокачанного файла, берете остаток от целочисленного деления `long tail = fileSize % 4096` и отбрасываете. И отвыкайте использовать `var`, используйте целевой тип, код будет читабельнее.

Comment: @aepot Про читаемость я бы поспорил) Если это "неведомый" тип, то да, согласен, но если мы видим четко, что `var result = "value";` (string) или `var someClass = new SomeClass()` (некий класс), то какой смысл в дублирование и написание подряд `SomeClass`? Также студия при наведение на переменную выдает ее тип без проблем, так что тут дело удобства больше, а не читаемость. По поводу отбрасывания спасибо, попробую завтра чуть переписать код с использованием `Range` и вашего отбрасывания.

Comment: Про использование var - это вообще древний холивар :) а с последней студией и последним решарпером вообще стало не актуально (кто то из них подсвечивает тип переменной, если она как var объявлена)

Comment: @aepot Попробовал я с остатком поиграться, сделал вычисление текущего размера "огрызка", прописал потом нечто такое `_fileSize -= _fileSize % _bufferSize;`, качаю файл 100мб, закрывая/открывая приложение раз 20, в итоге получаю 2-3 места в файле, где битые/недостающие байты. Сделал такой [костыль](https://pastebin.com/JvEXahSA) и вроде битья файла нет. Вот не пойму, что я упускаю, не уж то надо и правда все время делать на 1 буфер назад для надежности.

Comment: по хвосту я бы вот так посчитал
`tail = fileSize % bufferSize;`
`if (tail == 0) tail += bufferSize;`
`fileSize -= fileSize > bufferSize ? tail : fileSize;` так как сбой может быть и на нулевом буфере

Comment: Кстати, у `FileStream` стоит буфер 4096. И если он не заполнен, то он точно не будет записан на диск при закрытии программы, даже если в нем что-то есть. Пока не придумал, что с этим можно сделать. Собственно из-за него и приходится делать шагать еще на буфер в зад. Я бы кстати не стал использовать такой маленький буфер для записи в файл, потому что стоит минимизировать количество обращений к диску. Есть конечно `filestream.Flush()`, но как его вызвать при закрытии программы, пока не понятно.

Comment: @aepot Хм, с `FileSteam` вы скорей всего правы. А вот код ваш, увы, выдает в итоге битый файл. Размер хвоста выдал к примеру `119`. С сервера попросил данные в итоге на `119` байт "раньше" и в итоге этого недостаточно, данные бьются, причем размер этих "дыр" всегда разный. Короче все же надо полностью откатываться на 1 буфер и качать с него.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ хорошо, учтите тогда вариант, когда размер файла меньше 2 буферов, чтобы шаг назад в минус не сделать :) Еще хотел изначально посоветовать увеличить буфер, как минимум раза в 2. Это сделает в 2 раза меньше итераций и меньше будет нагружать диск. У меня 16кб буфер на загрузке данных стоит, потому что 8кб грузил проц (про 4кб я молчу), но у меня скорость загрузки выше 50 Мбит/с была. Поэтому для вас 8кб будет оптимально, кмк.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем да, спасибо всем, что помогли и натолкнули на [Заголовок Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/Range).

- Сделал метод, который возвращает текущий размер файла с "откатом" на размер буфера:

  ```
  private long GetFileSize()
  {
      long? fileSize = null;
      if (_isExist)
      {
          fileSize = new FileInfo(_destinationFilePath)?.Length;

          var tail = fileSize % _bufferSize;
          if (tail != 0) fileSize -= _bufferSize;
      }

      return fileSize ?? 0L;
  }
  ```

  Результатом он выдаст либо 0, либо `размер файла - размер буфера`.
- Дальше переписал отправку запроса на такое:

  ```
  var request = new HttpRequestMessage { RequestUri = new Uri(_downloadUrl) };
  request.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(_fileSize, null);
  using var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
  ```

  - `RangeHeaderValue(_fileSize, null);` - отправляем серверу размер ранее полученного файла и берем весь остаток. Если 0 - сервер отдает все.
  - `_httpClient.SendAsync(...)` - отправляем на сервер GET запрос с `Range` заголовком.
- У `FileStream` установил `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`, чтоб файл не перезписывало.
- Перед чтением данных с сервера задаю позицию `FileStream` на размер файла, который ранее получили:

  ```
  fileStream.Seek(_fileSize, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  ```

Собственно и все, что необходимо для продолжения скачивания файла. Сам код сейчас примерно такой (черновик):

```
public class DownloadManager : IDisposable
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    private readonly string _downloadUrl;
    private readonly string _destinationFilePath;
    private long _fileSize;
    private long? _totalFileSize;
    private bool _isExist;
    private const int _bufferSize = 8192;

    private int _connections;

    public delegate void ProgressChangedHandler(long? totalFileSize, long totalBytesDownloaded, double? progressPercentage);
    public event ProgressChangedHandler ProgressChanged;

    public DownloadManager(string downloadUrl, string destinationFilePath)
        => (_downloadUrl, _destinationFilePath, _httpClient)
        = (downloadUrl, destinationFilePath, new HttpClient());

    public async Task StartDownload()
    {
        bool isConnect = false;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                using var sizeRequest = await _httpClient.GetAsync(_downloadUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
                _totalFileSize = sizeRequest.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
                isConnect = true;
                _connections = 0;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                _connections++;
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            }

        } while (!isConnect && _connections <= 15);

        if (!isConnect) return;

        _isExist = File.Exists(_destinationFilePath);
        _fileSize = GetFileSize();

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage { RequestUri = new Uri(_downloadUrl) };
        request.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(_fileSize, null);
        using var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        await DownloadFileFromHttpResponseMessage(response);
    }

    private async Task DownloadFileFromHttpResponseMessage(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{response.StatusCode}]: {response.RequestMessage}");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            using var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            await ProcessContentStream(_totalFileSize, contentStream);
        }
        else
        {
            if (_fileSize != _totalFileSize)
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }

    private async Task ProcessContentStream(long? totalDownloadSize, Stream contentStream)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[_bufferSize];
        var totalBytesRead = _fileSize;
        var isMoreToRead = true;
        var readCount = 0L;

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_destinationFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, _bufferSize, true))
        {
            fileStream.Seek(_fileSize, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            do
            {
                int bytesRead = 0;

                try
                {
                    bytesRead = await contentStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

                    await fileStream.FlushAsync();
                    fileStream.Close();
                    fileStream.Dispose();
                    await StartDownload();
                    return;
                }


                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    isMoreToRead = false;
                    TriggerProgressChanged(totalDownloadSize, totalBytesRead);
                    continue;
                }

                await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                readCount += 1;

                if (readCount % 100 == 0)
                    TriggerProgressChanged(totalDownloadSize, totalBytesRead);
            }
            while (isMoreToRead);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(_destinationFilePath.GetMD5());
    }

    private void TriggerProgressChanged(long? totalDownloadSize, long totalBytesRead)
    {
        if (ProgressChanged == null)
            return;

        double? progressPercentage = null;
        if (totalDownloadSize.HasValue)
            progressPercentage = Math.Round((double)totalBytesRead / totalDownloadSize.Value * 100, 2);

        ProgressChanged(totalDownloadSize, totalBytesRead, progressPercentage);
    }

    private long GetFileSize()
    {
        long? fileSize = null;
        if (_isExist)
        {
            fileSize = new FileInfo(_destinationFilePath)?.Length;

            var tail = fileSize % _bufferSize;
            if (tail != 0) fileSize -= _bufferSize;
        }

        return fileSize ?? 0L;
    }

    public void Dispose() => _httpClient?.Dispose();
}
```

Издевательства по типу:

- Открытие/закрытие окна каждые 3-5%.
- Отключение интернета.
- Заморозки процесса на длительное время.

код успешно прошел, файл всегда докачивался и имел всегда верный Md5 и размер.
Осталось подчистить, привести все в порядок, пару проверок добавить, событий и можно использовать)

Comment: Я в своем коде тоже репорчу прогресс загрузки, и дергаю коллбэк только когда количество загруженных процентов меняется по отношению к прошлой итерации. Но у меня только прогрессбар на основе процентов, поэтому обновлять его больше чем 100 раз за 1 файл нет смысла. Хотя, у меня 1 ответ API не больше 25 мегабайт весит и приезжает за считанные секунды. А так, отличная работа! Приятно видеть восьмой шарп здесь. :) Еще увидел крутой и хитрый синтаксис в конструкторе, спасибо!

Comment: @aepot Тут все зависит от размера файла, надо бы это вовсе сделать динамическим значением, ибо если я поставлю большое значение для маленького файла, то выдаст всего +- пару значений (например если поставлю 1000, то выдаст 63% и 100% при загрузке файла в 10мб), вот высчитать бы как то это число под размер файла, чтоб выводило всего только раз в 1%.

Comment: Легко `int progress = 0` `int oldProgress = 0` и в цикле `totalBytesRead += bytesRead` `oldProgress = progress` `progress = (int)(totalBytesRead * 100 / totalDownloadSize)` `if (oldProgress != progress) TriggerProgressChanged(progress)`

Comment: То есть в отчетное событие можно отправлять уже высчитанное процентное значение.

Comment: @aepot Высчитывать процент каждую итерацию как по мне не очень хорошо, тут наверно стоит сделать нечто такое: `var quota = _totalFileSize.Value / _bufferSize / 100;` и высчитывать/выводить процент уже тогда, когда `readCount % quota == 0`.

Comment: А буфер тут при чем? Просто `скачано * 100 / всего` К тому же считать каждую итерацию используя целочисленные операции - это очень дешево по нагрузке. Именно поэтому я сначала умножаю на 100, а потом делю на размер файла. А каст идет `long -> int`.

Comment: @aepot Так мы не процент высчитываем, а то значение остатка, которое проверяем. Высчитывается только раз при старте и дальше уже просто идет проверка на остаток и если он равен 0, то высчитываем текущий процент.

Comment: Вот я например качаю файл в 1гб (`1073741824`), значение `quota = 1310` (буфер `8192`). Высчитывание самого процента идет почти тогда, [когда и надо](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YojG5.gif), все остальное время идет запись в файл и +1 к счетчику. Вроде самый оптимальный вариант.

Comment: Ну, вам виднее :) Мне подошел как раз вариант с вызыванием колбэка только когда в UI что-то должно поменяться, а у меня там целые проценты без других деталей. В вашем же случае, если отчет о загруженных данных происходит чаще, чем 1 раз в 1%, то надо сделать точность в `0.1%`, будет аккуратнее смотреться. И отформатировать байты `.ToString("N0")`, будет выглядеть читабельнее. У процентов еще можно лидирующий пробел, а не ноль. :)