# Асинхронное скачивание файлов по очереди

Tags: c#

Я написал метод асинхронного скачивания файлов по очереди, файлы берутся из листа. Также, есть показ скорости загрузки, процентов, размер файлов и размер скачавшихся файлов. Есть хостинг, с которого большие файлы не качаются через обычный DownloadFile. Ошибка "Неожиданный EOF или 0 байт из транспортного потока." `DownloadFile("ссылка", @"куда качать");` - вот это не работает с большими файлами, больше в коде ничего нет. Очень много гуглил - бесполезно, чего только не делал. Написал консультанту на хостинге, он отправил сообщение системному администратору, попросили прислать StackTrace - прислал. Ждал ночь. В итоге написали мне мол проблему решить не удалось, можем посоветовать использовать поддержку докачки файлов. И дал мне такой код:

```
        private void DownloadFile()
    {
        string sSourceURL = "файл на сервере";
        string sDestinationPath = @"D:\file.gz";

        long iFileSize = 0;
        int iBufferSize = 1024;
        iBufferSize *= 1000;
        long iExistLen = 0;
        FileStream saveFileStream;
        if (File.Exists(sDestinationPath))
        {
            FileInfo fINfo = new FileInfo(sDestinationPath);
            iExistLen = fINfo.Length;
        }
        if (iExistLen > 0)
            saveFileStream = new FileStream(sDestinationPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        else
            saveFileStream = new FileStream(sDestinationPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        HttpWebRequest hwRq;
        HttpWebResponse hwRes;
        hwRq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sSourceURL);
        hwRq.AddRange((int)iExistLen);
        Stream smRespStream;
        hwRes = (HttpWebResponse)hwRq.GetResponse();
        smRespStream = hwRes.GetResponseStream();
        iFileSize = hwRes.ContentLength;
        int iByteSize;
        byte[] downBuffer = new byte[iBufferSize];
        while ((iByteSize = smRespStream.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            saveFileStream.Write(downBuffer, 0, iByteSize);
        }
        saveFileStream.Close();
    }
```

И о чудо! Я вставил ссылку и файл скачался, при чем теперь можно закрывать программу, открыть ее заново и файл начнет качание не заново, он докачает столько, сколько не докачал. Но мне нужно узнавать постоянно размер скачавшихся файлов, скорость скачивания и нужна пауза. Вот мой код, в котором это все есть: Лишнее убрал, чтобы было поменьше, оставил самое важное.

```
public static async void DownloadFiles(IEnumerable<string> exfiles) // Ассинхронное скачивание файлов один за одним
    {
        App.MW.Stop = false;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        string DownloadFile = "";
        try
        {

            double size = 0; // Размер всех файлов
            double downloaded_tmp = 0; // Сколько байт скачивающегося файла уже скачалось
            double downloaded = 0; // Сколько байт из всех файлов скачалось
            int progress = 0; // Процент скачавшихся данных (0-100)

            foreach (var file in exfiles) // Проходим по списку и получаем размер всех файлов
            {
                size += GetFileSize(new Uri("https://site" + file));
            }

            using (var http = new WebClient())
            {
                http.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
                {
                    if (App.MW.Stop == true)
                    {
                        http.Dispose();
                        http.CancelAsync();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        downloaded_tmp = e.BytesReceived; // Сколько байт от скачивающегося файла скачалось
                        progress = (int)((downloaded + downloaded_tmp) / size * 100); // Получаем процент скачавшихся данных


                        App.MW.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                            App.MW.DownloadBar.Value = progress; 
                            App.MW.DownloadLabel2.Content = Math.Round((size / 1073741824)*progress/100, 3) + "гб из " + Math.Round(size / 1073741824, 3) + "гб";
                            var speed = Math.Round(e.BytesReceived / 1024 / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
                            App.MW.DownloadLabel.Content = progress + " % (" + Math.Round(speed / 1024, 3) + "мб/сек)";
                        });

                        if (progress == 100 || size * progress / 100 == size || size * progress / 100 > size)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("готово");
                        }
                    }
                };

                http.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) => {
                    downloaded += downloaded_tmp;

                };

                foreach (var file in exfiles)
                {
                    if (App.MW.Stop == true)
                    {
                        await App.MW.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate ()
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("загрузка остановлена");
                        }));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DownloadFile = file;
                        await App.MW.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate ()
                        {
                            App.MW.filesStatusLabel.Text = file;
                        }));

                        try
                        {
                            sw.Start();
                            await http.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri("сайт" + file), file);  
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception E) { MessageBox.Show(E.ToString()); }
    }
```

Код, который скинул консультант, там же даже нет DownloadFile, он работает по другому принципу. Помогите пожалуйста, как сделать все тоже самое что в моем методе в код, который скинул консультант. Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Я не думаю, что вы на `WebClient` сможете такое сделать, ибо он является некой "надстройкой" над `HttpWebRequest` (которую вам дал консультант), другими словами, `HttpWebRequest` - это более низкоуровневый класс, который не имеет методов загрузки и событий отслеживания. Тут вам скорей всего придется делать свой класс, наследовать его от `WebClient`, переопределять внутренние его запросы `HttpWebRequest` и тогда будет у вас этот франкенштейн, да. Ну а вообще, я советую вам отказаться от этих классов, ибо они уже давно в C# являются устаревшими, для новой разработки используйте `HttpClient`.

Comment: `iByteSize` - размер полученной порции данных. Посчитать процент - обычная пропорция. Сделать паузку - вставляйте её в цикл `while`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov iByteSize не обновляется почему-то постоянно. Почему? Добавил лабел, в while написал чтобы этот текст изменялся на iByteSize. Текст не изменяется. Можно в этот цикл через system,io узнавать размер просто, но, все таки, почему iByteSize не обновляется? И можете еще подсказать пожалуйста, как узнавать скорость скачивания?

Comment: Используйте `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`, он реализует нормальный `async`/`await`, а в .NET Core еще и работает быстрее в несколько раз. [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1110487/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-httpclient/1110885#1110885), посмотрите, человек недавно грыз подобную задачу.