# Показ текущего статуса нескольких процессов запущенных через Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Посредством такой конструкции

```
Parallel.ForEach(_targetTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>(), ReadData);
```

запускается несколько процессов обработки, параметры которой переданы в таблице *_targetTable*. Нужно вывести в окне приложения статус для каждого процесса (например, запрос данных, получение данных, обработка результатов, сохранение), сам прогресс (проценты) не нужны.
Прочитал, что можно воспользоваться интерфейсом

```
IProgress<T>
```

но все примеры только для одного потока. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно организовать вывод текущего статуса для всех потоков?

Спасибо

Comment: `_targetTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()` и MVVM, вы серьезно? По поводу вашей задачи я бы сделал так: Отдельный класс, который отвечает за скачивание файла, у которого есть событие "изменения статуса", класс имеет `Task`, который запускает например загрузку. Ну а дальше все просто: 1. Создали класс, подписались на событие, запустили `Task`. Если таких задач много, то формируете список тасков.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ что не так с приведением типа в MVVM? Допустим оформлю обработку в отдельный класс, по прежнему стоит вопрос, как из потока вернуть его текущий статус (чем он сейчас занимается). По условию задачи мне нужно не только его скачать, но и обработать согласно правил и вернуть результат. Может я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: `что не так с приведением типа в MVVM?` - то, что MVVM, это строгое разделение на слои, где VM слой не должен совершенно нечего знать про View слой и наоборот, View не должен нечего знать про VM и M слой. Вы используете `_targetTable`, это явно компонент таблицы (контрол), а значит, вы используете либо подписку на событие и через него обращаетесь к контролу, либо делаете это напрямую, что является грубым нарушением MVVM.

Comment: `как из потока вернуть его текущий статус` - Во первых где вы увидели поток, а во вторых что вам не понятно в событиях? [Вот я делал недавно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1110885/220553) загрузчик, там есть событие `ProgressChanged`, которое из кода вызывается. Сама загрузка файла запускается при помощи `Task` асинхронно. Вот прям берите тот код, делайте список задач и запускайте их при помощи `Task.WhenAll()` например.

Comment: По поводу DataTable позвольте с Вами не согласиться, так как это элемент самого фреймворка, это такая-же структура данных как List или Dictionary. Потоки создаются (используются) при использовании класса Parallel (по крайней мере так пишут в книгах. В моём случае VM ничего не знает про V. В свою очередь, V читает VM. Из набора потоков надо получать статус. Пока вижу вариант только событиями, но как использовать IProgress?

Comment: Соглашаться или нет - дело ваше, можете почитать про MVVM подход и поймете, что основная его суть в том, что бы отделить View от Model, что бы одна команда могла делать интерфейс, не думая как работает логика взаимодействия с базой (например), а другая команда могла написать ту самую логику работы с базой, не думая о том, что есть в интерфейсе. Вот удалите весь свой XAML, запустится проект? Я думаю, что нет, а должен. `такая-же структура данных как List или Dictionary` - вы о `DataGrid` или что там у вас? Нечего подобного, это элемент отображения, но не хранения данных.

Comment: `Из набора потоков надо получать статус.` - Не путайте многопоточность и асинхронность. Асинхронность, это совсем другая вещь, которая не связана с потоками. В асинхронности вы создаете `Task`, которые не чем не отличаются от простых методов за исключением `async/await`, которые говорят "ей, процессор, выполни пока что-то другое, пока я жду эту задачу". Вот как бы вы сделали это без потоков и прочего? Наверно бы создали `List` из ваших файлов, необходимые для скачивания и запустили бы в них загрузку, так? Файл - был бы классом, который имел бы event об изменение статуса. Ну так в чем проблема?

Comment: Я говорю не о DataGrid (который является контролом), а о DataTable, который является коллекцией (прописан в System.Data), поэтому в он не является частью View, но DataGrid может биндится к DataTable (не напрямую, конечно)
Класс Parallel работает с пулом потоков, отсюда делаю вывод, что метод, переданный ему работает параллельно в потоках. Каждая итерация цикла, созданная классом, работает параллельно (одновременно), независимо от UI потока. В этот поток нужно передать текущее состояние каждой итерации. Как я их буду отображать - это уже решу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=netcore-3.1), вызов колбэка `IProgress` осуществляется с перенаправлением в `SynchronizationContext` того потока, который его создал. Следовательно, он является своего рода потокобезопасным способом отчитываться о прогрессе.

> Any handler provided to the constructor or event handlers registered with the `ProgressChanged` event are invoked through a `SynchronizationContext` instance captured when the instance is constructed.

Поэтому, вы можете просто создать поле типа `IProgress`, записать туда экземпляр класса `Progress` с коллбэком, и все должно заработать, независимо от того, в одном потоке будет выполняться итератор, или в нескольких.

Можно реализовать через поле

```csharp
private readonly IProgress<string> _myProgress = new Progress(s =>
{
    Status = s; // предположим, что к Status привязан TextBlock через Binding
});
```

или через свойство с "ленивой" инициализацией

```csharp
private IProgress<string> _myProgress;

public IProgress<string> MyProgress => _myProgress ?? (_myProgress = new Progress(s =>
{
    Status = s;
}));
```

Только лучше убедиться, что первое обращение к `MyProgress` будет из UI потока.

ну или свойство без ленивой инициализации

```csharp
public IProgress<string> MyProgress { get; } = new Progress(s =>
{
    Status = s;
});
```

А внутри итератора просто вызывайте `Report()`.

```csharp
private void ReadData(DataRow dataRow)
{
    MyProgress.Report("my status");
}
```

Через `IProgress` можно передавать объект любого типа, не обязательно строку.

Comment: А в ReadData _myProgress передавать не надо? достаточно его объявить вне цикла?

Comment: @АртемийСоболев да, можно просто глобально, передать его в итератор конечно можно попробовать, но зачем, если обратная связь идет через синхронизацию контекста и делагат `Action`? Грубо говоря `Report` - это вызов колбэка, метода, а не просто типа глобальная переменная. Вы же выносите в методы класса повторяющийся код, а не объявляете их локально, и считаете это нормальным, вот и здесь я не вижу ничего не нормального. :) Для еще большей уверенности, можете его сделать свойством с одним `{ get; }` или `readonly` полем.

Comment: @АртемийСоболев дополнил ответ