# Как адекватно реализовать передачу больших файлов на сервер ASP.NET и с него на клиент?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api, fileupload

ASP.NET 8 web-api с MVC (без View, фронт отдельно будет (браузер, десктоп)).
Нужен адекватный способ, чтоб большой файл загружать на сервер и скачивать с сервера, при этом он не должен весь находиться в ОЗУ (получить часть файла, записать на диск или в контейнер minio, удалить из ОЗУ). Должно быть удобно для меня и фронта, и желательно велосипеды не писать. И должна быть уверенность, что если отправлять много файлов на сервер параллельно, то часть отправок будет отклонена (не будет сохранять в ОЗУ тела запросов), если для них не хватит ОЗУ, и сервер не отвалится.

Пока в мыслях такое, но сомневаюсь в адекватности этого:

```
[HttpPost]
public long UploadFileRequest([FromBody]FileInfo fileInfo/*информация о файле. название, размер, тип контента в нем, ...*/)
{
    return 0; //id загружаемого файла
}
        
[HttpPost]
public void UploadFilePart([FromForm] long id /*id файла*/, long partId /*может пригодиться, чтоб не перепутать части в случае проблем*/, [FromForm]Stream partStream /*Тут будут байты части файла*/)
{
   //сохранить байты из того потока на диск
}
    
//уведомить сервер, что весь файл передан.
[HttpGet]
public void UploadFinish([FromQuery]long id){}
```

И еще на сокетах что-то подобное.

Comment: Не думаю, что тут будет проблема с ОЗУ, ибо файлы обычно напрямую пишут/читают на/с диск/a при помощи простых `Stream`, это достаточно для многих случаев. Ну а если загрузка на сервер не удалась, то начинать по новой (не знаю ни одного сайта, который позволял бы "догрузить" файл на сервер). Так что, логика должна быть простая: получаем Stream клиента, открываем файл для записи, копируем из потока в поток небольшим куском. Как только файл закачался, проверяем, даем уникальный ID, записываем в базу.

Comment: Если говорить про загрузку с сервера, то там аналогично, НО, в этом случае есть [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range), благодаря которому вы можете клиенту начать отдавать только то, что он просит. Вам также надо просто открыть поток, "сдвинуть" его в нужную позицию, начать отдавать байты, все. Аналогичный финт можно в теории и для загрузки на сервер прикрутить, но смысла чет в этом я не вижу...

Comment: То есть условный httpClient на клиенте и return stream на сервере сами со всем этим разберутся, будут делать несколько http запросов/ответов?

Comment: Не совсем. На сервере да, просто `Stream` и в теории будет работать без проблем, НО, диск у вас ведь один, а это будет значит вашим слабым звеном, ибо если откроется сразу куча `Stream` и писать туда асинхронно, то диске ведь пишет синхронно, передвигая головку в нужный сектор) Поэтому если файлов прям уйма за раз, то стоит подумать об модернизации сервера, ну а если речь идет о нескольких файлах за раз, то в теории проблем не будет. Что касается клиента - если используете `Range` заголовок, то `HttpClient` надо этому научить, например [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1110885/220553).